# Writing JS to Store 10 Values But TypeError: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

i Am Writing A JavaScript Function In React For Adding 10 Values To Array
This 10 Values To Be Stored From Html Input Field
So what i did is added input field with id 'tsk ' and button 'bt3' so whenever the button get hit it run a js script which takes the value of input field 'tsk' and pushed it to empty array in js
so every time i hit button the value inside field is pushed to array
and prompt over label 'list ' by using innerHTML method

here my efforts of html is

```
 <div id='array'>
      <input type='number' id='tsk'>push 10 values</input>
      <label htmlFor='list' id='list' >List values are:</label>
      <button id='bt3' onClick={tsk3}>ADD Value</button>
    </div>
```

and here is corresponding js to run it

```
function tsk3()
{
  let item = document.getElementById('tsk').value;
  var array =[1,];
  array.push(item);
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML=array;
}
```

but instead of working  the code it showing me unnecessary type error[OUTPUT OF WEBPAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcWrF.png)

Comment: It's just as the error says - why are you adding a child to an `<input>`? And why are you using native DOM methods if you're using React?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I didn't understand i am new to react but before this i write two more script containing <input> tag and they are working pretty good But can you elaborate  it more where my code is laging

Comment: @CertainPerformance Pls Do Something I Didn't getting a clarity in answer

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. You might be better off with an introductory React tutorial if you're trying to use React - don't use DOM methods when using React.

Comment: `<input>` tags cannot have content. They can have a `value` attribute, but an `<input>` cannot have anything "inside" of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because in React when void elements have either children or `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop. HTML elements such as  are void elements that are only self-closing without any content. Therefore, React will throw an exception if you set either children or the innerHTML property for a void element.
Also, there are syntax errors in your code. The htmlFor property sets or returns the value of the for attribute of a label. The htmlFor attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to which in your case should be 'tsk' i.e the input element. Accordingly,  the label tag should appear before the input tag, something like the following -

```html
<div id='array'>
      <label htmlFor='task' id='list' >List values are:</label>
      <input type='number' id='tsk' placeholder='push 10 values'/>
      <button id='bt3' onClick={tsk3}>ADD Value</button>
</div>
```

Also note input has to be a self-closing tag.

Comment: Thnx @Bidisha It Actually Worked

Comment: `<input>` tags do not have to be self-closing. In HTML, the `/>` is completely ignored.